# Run bundle install as a background process

Tags: ruby, shell, unix, bundler

I want to run `bundle install` as a background process and hide its output from the terminal.
Currently I do this

```
bundle > /dev/null &
```

but maybe there is a better and shorter way do achieve the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really aren't concerned with its output (and whether it succeeds or fails), you can also redirect the stderr of the process:

```
bundle >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```